# Best way to implement Notification system using Nodejs and Postgresql Database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

currently i'am developing a  react app where user can post and comment and like a post.
so i did everything but there is one more thing that i want to do which is getting notification after user
Post or maybe comment and so on..
so let say i have a table called 'posts' in the database (PostgreSQL) and when user called "A" create post ,that post inserted into the database and then i want to receive a notification which Said that the user "A" created a post with the ID of that post and i think the main idea here is to watch the table of posts  and whenever a new raw inserted a notification fire.
i searched many sources and find that i can use Pusher ,web-socket but to be honest i can't make a decision without figuring out the best way to achieve that.
 So How i can  get notified hence a new row inserted into the table "posts" ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Salah, I have the same need. I'm to establish a `Listen/Notify` communication with Node. But this is generic for all, that is when a new Answer comes in, everyone gets a notification regardless he or she is related to the post/question. This app notification should be based on whom this Answer is for, and only send to User A or B. Do you know how to implement? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres has [`LISTEN/NOTIFY`](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/07/postgresql-listen-notify/) that you could use in conjunction with an on-insert trigger on the `posts` table.

Some process can then be listening for those notifications and figure out whom to send the notification to (via whichever transport you choose).

However, I think you might be better off adding a concrete table for notifications, so the user can see notifications that occurred when they weren't connected to the notification transport.

Comment: thank you so much  for the answer @AKX ,and a lot recommended to use Listen and Notify that PostgreSQL provided.

Comment: Good recommendation. Is there any sample app like you described? Thank you!